# How can one enable a shell command line argument for a python package installed for pip?

Tags: python, pip, pypi

So for a python package, how do you enable a command line argument from a pip installed package? Here is an example, for a package called mrbob:

```
$ pip install mrbob
$ mrbob DoSomethingFunction
```

How can a command line option and a new shell command be enabled for a python package?

Comment: If the package doesn't support this functionality, you have to write your own CLI wrapper.

Comment: `mrbob` would have to be added to the system PATH

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With [`setuptools`](https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/index.html), define a `console_script` entry point:

```
setup(
    # other arguments here...
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': [
            'mrbob = my_package.some_module:main_func',
        ]
    }
)
```

See [automatic script creation](https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/setuptools.html#automatic-script-creation) in the `setuptools` docs for more details.

With [`distutils`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/distutils/index.html), use `scripts`:

```
setup(...,
      scripts=['scripts/mrbob']
      )
```

See [installing scripts](https://docs.python.org/3.5/distutils/setupscript.html#installing-scripts) in the `distutils` docs for more details.

Answer (score 0):

`mrbob` will be installed in the `bin` directory
e.g. in my case it is in:

`/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/`

As long as this is in your `$PATH` you are good.

Comment: Is "your", "you", and "are" really so hard to type out?